Getting this error . A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
Here is react native version : 0.66.1,
Java versions : openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.28+13-CA (build 17+35-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.28+13-CA (build 17+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing),
Here is code where i have compildeSdk ,
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"

    minSdkVersion = 21

    compileSdkVersion = 28

    targetSdkVersion = 28

    // Choose desired NDK version

    ndkVersion = "21.0.6113669"
}

android {

    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    // Configure compile options

    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility 1.8

        targetCompatibility 1.8

    }

    // Define default configuration for the application


    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "*******"`your text`

        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion

        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode 4

        versionName "1.3"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true



        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

Here is distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
